# How many entries can autocomplete in Excel 2013 handle?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, autocomplete

When typing a text entry into a cell which already exists in a row above, Excel supports autocomplete (while you type), so you only need to type "**al**" to get "**al**pha":

[image]

My question is:

**How many lines of "beta"** (or random, pair-wise different strings) can there be **before autocomplete stops working for "alpha"?**

I tried doing it for 26000 rows and it didn't work (I could only autocomplete if I happened to pick one of the last few rows - it appears as if the autocomplete feature looked only "locally" in a few cells around the target cell).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a definitive answer, even the fact that there is a limit seems undocumented.

The answer seems to depend on the context:

- in a list of ~1000 entries, around 137 rows away from alpha the autocomplete stops working
- in a list of ~200 entries, autocomplete still works in row 200

This is with MS Excel 2013 on Win 8.1 - not sure if this depends on any of this...